# Unreal Engine: how to activate the keyboard?

Tags: unreal-engine4, game-development, blueprint, unreal-blueprint

In my game I have a pause menu, I activate it with Q button. Then I can press continue button using mouse to deactivate it. It works, but I want to be able to deactivate it with Q button, but function SetInputModeUIOnly disable keyboard

Can't call red blocks, because boolean variable don't cnange it's value because of the deactivated keyboard

[image]

That's why I tried to override it like here https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/367338/bp-set-input-mode-ui-only.html , but is still don't work

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use the "Set Game Paused" node?

[image]

Make sure the InputAction node is set to "Execute When Paused". Otherwise you won't be able to unpause.